# Proving an operator $D: L^2[0,1]\rightarrow C'$, $Df(t)=\int^t_0 f(s) ds$ is unitary

Tags: operator-theory, banach-spaces, hilbert-spaces

Let $C'\subseteq C[0,1]$ be the space of all absolutely continuous function such that $f(0)=0$ and $f' \in L^2[0,1]$.  Define an inner product on $C'$ as $\langle f,g \rangle = \int^1_0 f'(t)g'(t)dt$.  $C'$ is a Hilbert space with this inner product.  Define an operator $D: L^2[0,1]\rightarrow C'$ as $Df(t)=\int^t_0 f(s) ds$.  This operator is unitary "clearly" according to a book I am reading.  However, it is not clear to me.  Maybe I am missing something incredible obvious but I have tried several things and can't seem to prove that $D$ is unitary.  I would appreciate if someone could tell me why this is "clearly" true.  Thanks!

Comment: Every source I've seen demands that unitary operators must be from a Hilbert space onto itself, which your $D$ is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the Lebesgue differentiation theorem, $$(Df)^\prime(t)=\frac{d}{dt} \int_0^t f(s)ds=f(t)$$
for a.e. $t\in[0,1]$.
Therefore,
$$\langle Df, Dg\rangle_{C^\prime}=\int_0^1 (Df)^\prime(t) (Dg)^\prime(t) dt = \int_0^1 f(t) g(t) dt = \langle f,g\rangle_{L^2[0,1]}$$
so $D$ preserves the inner product. By the characterization of absolutely continuous functions by the Lebesgue differentiation theorem, $D$ is in fact a Hilbert space isomorphism. I guess that is what they mean by "unitary".

Comment: I forgot to use the $L^2[0,1]$ inner product for $\langle f,g \rangle$.  Thanks.  If I was evaluating $\langle Df,g \rangle$, which inner product would I use?  I want to find $D^*$ the adjoint which should be just $D^-1$ since D is unitary but I want to double check that makes sense.

Comment: You would use the inner product in $C^\prime$. Yes, the adjoint is $D^{-1}$, sending a function on its derivative.